# Perl web crawling framework

Tags: perl, frameworks, screen-scraping, web-crawler

I've been using Perl for years to crawl and scrape for various different purposes, one thing that's always bugged me is while there are tons of great CPAN modules for small-scale scraping and crawling, such as LWP, WWW::Mechanize, Web::Scraper, AnyEvent::HTTP, and now Mojo::UserAgent, there don't appear to be any crawling frameworks in the same way as there are for other languages.

For example Apache Nutch (/Droids) & Scrapy (Python).

Anybody know of any projects at all in Perl that are equivalent?

Comment: See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1055183 and https://metacpan.org/pod/Scrappy

Comment: Interesting thanks although as noted in the string Scrappy seems to have stagnated. Good compilation of tools there but still lacking a framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to take a look at modules such as [HTML::Robot::Scraper](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Robot::Scrapper) or
[HTTP::UserAgentString::Robot](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::UserAgentString::Robot) and I think there are a few more with [robot](https://metacpan.org/search?q=robot) in their name.

Comment: Thanks - HTML::Robot::Scrapper seems the closest to what I'm thinking of; as per Python's Scrapy would be great for Perl to have a canonical, full-on crawling framework with full interactive shell etc etc. Sort of like Mojolicious/Dancer etc just for extensible, parallel, distributed crawling.

Mojolicious brought me back to Perl for web dev, have to say the scraping frameworks in Python/Ruby are pulling me away :/

Comment: Why don't you implement the most awesome scraping module for Perl then?

Comment: Haha would love to - unfortunately a bit beyond my skill level right now but maybe some day :)